# SQL log database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need a database for logging diffent events.

I have a main table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log` (
  `log_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `log_label` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `log_level` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `log_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `log_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`)
)
```

So I have chosen and make a side table to contain any value for a main log. The value can be dynamic.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_data` (
  `log_data_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `log_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `log_data_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `log_data_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`log_data_id`)
)
```

Will I get some problems / limitations, When I need to recive data via php and mysql?

An example would be to fetch all logs with "log_type = error"
How should I join all data from log_data table?

Comment: What do you mean with "dynamic" database?

Comment: With dynamic i mean. The data in the table log_data can bee different based on the type of log.
Dynamic database might be a wrong term to use :)
I have removed the word dynamic.

Comment: You need to explain what kind of output you want to get, it's not really clear what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking a longer text column for log messages; `varchar(255)` is tiny.

The design is a strange hybrid:

- if you want a "generic" design, most fields of `log` should be demoted to `log_data`.
- if you want to log fundamentally different types of event, you should use specialized and independent tables for each type, without clunky "side tables":

  ```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chat_membership_log` 
  (
  log_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  log_time datetime NOT NULL,
  event_type char(1),--'J'=join, 'L'=leave
  username varchar(40), 
  PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`)
  )

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `application_crash_log` 
  (
  log_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  log_time datetime NOT NULL,
  PID varchar(20), 
  command_line varchar(2000),
  PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`)
  )
  ```